# Vmx file not opening

Tags: vmware, kali

I have a vmx file on my Ubuntu machine and I need to configure it because Kali Linux is not allowing me to use my wireless adapter I found the vmx file the one I click on it it says there's no software available to open the file what is the best method for me to go about this